# Add new tuple to list if first element is not already in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, matching

I am wanting to add a new tuple to a list of tuples only if the first element nickName is not already in the list. I can get it to match if both the userName and nickName are in the list, but I cant get it to just match if the nickname is in there.

```
nickList = []

def NICK(addr,clientMessage):

    nickName = clientMessage[1]
    userName = clientMessage[3]
    if (nickName, userName) not in nickList:
        nickList.append((nickName,userName))
        response = 'NICK and USER successfully added to list'
        UDPServerSocket.sendto(response.encode(), (addr))
    else:
        response = 'NICK already taken'
        UDPServerSocket.sendto(response.encode(), (addr))
```

This code will match if both the userName and nickName are already in the list, but I want it to only append the nickName and userName if ONLY the nickName is in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your condition to the following:

```
if nickName not in list(zip(*nickList))[0]
```

`zip(*)` iterates your list of tuples and aggregates each 1st element, each 2nd element, etc. We can then form a list and index the first element `[0]`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!